# Building a dynamic SQL query

Tags: c++, sql, oracle

I want to read `value` from the user and use it in my select query. How can I use a dynamic value in the SQL query?

My current code gives me this error:

> ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

This is my code:

```
void buildQuery()
{
    cout << "Enter flight no :";
    cin >> value;
    strcpy((char *)sql_statement.arr,"select fname from flights where  
    flno = " + value );      
    cout << "Query is  " << (char *) sql_statement.arr<< endl;
}

void executeQuery()
{
    sql_statement.len = strlen((char *) sql_statement.arr);
    exec sql PREPARE S1 FROM :sql_statement;
    exec sql declare C1 cursor FOR S1;
    exec sql open C1  ;
    while(1)
    {
       exec sql FETCH C1 INTO :fname;
       if ( sqlca.sqlcode !=  0)
       {
          cout << "past fetch..." <<endl;
          break;
       }

    cout << "Employee Name is: = " << (char *)ename.arr << endl;
    }
  exec sql close C1;
}
```

Comment: Please **edit** your question and enter the code as actual text, not as a link.

Comment: Writing a C++ program to query an Oracle database seems like a tough start point for somebody who is "new to coding".